# Should an outbound handler by default pass on a ChannelPromise?

Tags: exception, netty

There are very few (good) resources on best practices for how to do error handling in Netty, and my team has seen quite a few instances of errors being swallowed silently, which makes for less-than-nice debugging.

I was simply wondering if a good default strategy is to simply pass on the promise passed into `write()` when doing your won `ctx.write(msg,promise)`?

I wrote [a bunch of "learning/exploratory"](https://github.com/fatso83/test-driven-learning/blob/332cea2d07fc5ca47ebd568eaa8ae14f12113ef5/java-netty/src/test/java/tdl/OutHandlerBehaviourTest.java) tests to get a better feel for Netty's exception handling, and I found that an exception handler nearer the tail of the handler pipeline than the source of the exception would only have its promise listener called if every handler passed it on. Up until that point, we would usually just do `ctx.write(msg)`, losing the `ChannelPromise` that was sent in. Of course, should you wish to do something else and pass in another promise (`ctx.newPromise()`) you do that, but I am wondering if passing on a promise per default would make sense.

If so, why doesn't Netty do this per default? I would think that makes sense when a caller just calls the `ctx.write(msg)` overload, as most people don't want exceptions silently dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should pass on the `promise` if you implement `ChannelOutboundHandler`, in fact this is exactly the default implementation that is provided by `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter`. If you not pass on the `promise` you are responsible to full-fill it, which may either be done directly or by chaining it with another `ChannelPromise` that you create and pass on via a `write` at some point (or via the ChannelFuture that is returned by `ctx.write(Object)`

Comment: OK, so if I understand you correctly one should _always_ either do something with the promise or the channel future, as not doing so has a high risk of not handling errors that might arise. I suggest covering this and general exception handling strategies more thoroughly in a next revision of Netty in Practice (or other docs), as this isn't dealt with in the 3-4 pages (approx p. 94) that are allotted in the current edition. It mostly covers the _what_ (API), not the _how_,_why_,_when_ questions :)